# AutoHotkey L Clcik and Loop MouseMove Only

Tags: loops, autohotkey, mousemove, mouseclick-event, pause

Good day,

I am having issues getting a code to work more consistently.

The task I'm trying to accomplish is the ability to hold a LEFT click down and move mouse to loop ONLY between 2 specific coordinates moving mouse back and forth between the two coordinates.

Below is the code and the issue I've run into.

```
`::
BreakLoop = 1           ; ` Breaks The Loop
return              ; You must have a return after any multi line hotkey

^!0::                   ; Bind to Ctrl + Alt + 0
BreakLoop = 0           ; lets the hotkey reset the BreakLoop var when pressed

        MouseGetPos, px, py
        Sleep, 300
        MouseClick, L, %px%, %py%, , , D
        Sleep, 1000

Loop                ;Loop Script begins here
{
    if (BreakLoop = 1)  ; Breaks when Esc is pressed
    break

        MouseMove, 1069,  889
        Sleep, 100
        MouseMove, 840,  886
        Sleep, 100

}
return
```

The first portion of the code "MouseGetPos" section of 4 lines works I THINK as intended, but when it transitions into the loop section it does NOT consistently move the mouse to specified coordinates while still holding the down the "MouseClick" command. On one computer it seems to work almost always. On other computers instead of clicking and moving to indicated coordinates, it'll click and move in exact same location as "MouseGetPos" and start the loop code instead while shifting app screen to match the indicate coordinates.

2nd, I am hoping to input a pause of the loop so that I can have manual control of where to move the mouse, without the LEFT click command getting reset. So once I unpause the script it'll go back to looping between the 2 specific coordinates again.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem could be that the script never release the left mouse button. I would try to insert a     Click, Up    under the if statement, before the break. If you insert this you must close both in brackets. I can´t promise that this is the absolute solution, but i had soem similar problems in my own scripts that i could fixed with this addition.

Comment: Unless you are sure this answers the question, make it a comment, no an answer!

Comment: I am hoping to achieve not letting go of the click. The desired action is like a game where I click on a resource and drag over any said location by moving the mouse without letting go of the Left click and it'll fill storage bins

Comment: U. Windl I am new on this platform please can you explain me how I could add a comment to question without any existing answer.